# Required Field in React Form not Requiring Text Entry

Tags: reactjs, forms, material-ui, required

I have a subscription dialog form. I want the email field to be required, but I am currently able to submit my form with a blank email address (which would be a major problem for the client!). I have it marked as required in my code, but that doesn't seem to be translating to my UI.

I am using Material UI for styling.

Any pointers are sincerely appreciated :)

[image]

In the picture, see how I was able to click subscribe with no email address (the submit message appears after clicking subscribe).

```
import React from 'react';
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import TextField from '@material-ui/core/TextField';
import Dialog from '@material-ui/core/Dialog';
import DialogActions from '@material-ui/core/DialogActions';
import DialogContent from '@material-ui/core/DialogContent';
import DialogContentText from '@material-ui/core/DialogContentText';
import DialogTitle from '@material-ui/core/DialogTitle';
import Grid from '@material-ui/core/Grid';
import { Typography } from '@material-ui/core';
import { Form } from 'react-final-form';


const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  root: {
    flexGrow: 1,
    padding: theme.spacing(2)
  },
  divider: {
    marginBottom: theme.spacing(2)
  }
}));

export default function SubscribeFormResults() {

  const classes = useStyles();

  const [open, setOpen] = React.useState(false);
  const [formSubmitted, setFormSubmitted] = React.useState(false);

  const onSubmit = async values => {
    console.log('Submitting subscribe form!');
    console.log('Subscribe form values:', values);
  
    setFormSubmitted(true);
  };

  const handleClickOpen = () => {
    setOpen(true);
  };

  const handleClose = () => {
    setOpen(false);
    setFormSubmitted(false);
  };

  const validate = values => {
    const errors = {};
    if (!values.userEmail) {
      errors.userEmail = 'Required';
    }
    return errors;
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <Button size="small" color="primary" onClick={handleClickOpen}>
        Subscribe
      </Button>
      <Dialog open={open} onClose={handleClose} aria-labelledby="form-dialog-title">
        <DialogTitle id="form-dialog-title">Subscribe</DialogTitle>
          <DialogContent>
            <Form
            onSubmit={onSubmit}
            initialValues={{ userEmail: 'johndoe@example.com', arn: 'Connect to Backend!' }}
            validate={validate}
            render={({ handleSubmit, form, submitting, pristine, values }) => (
              <form onSubmit={handleSubmit} noValidate>

                <DialogContentText>
                  To subscribe to this website, please enter your email address here. We will send updates
                  occasionally.
                </DialogContentText>

                <TextField
                  label="Email Address"
                  name="userEmail"
                  margin="none"
                  required={true}
                  fullWidth
                />

                {formSubmitted && <Grid item xs={12}>
                  <Typography name='submitMessage' variant='subtitle1'>You have subscribed to AA-01-23-45-678901-2. {/* Connect to backend here */}</Typography>
                </Grid>}

                <DialogActions>
                  <Button /* onClick={handleClose} */ color="primary" type="submit" disabled={submitting}>
                    Subscribe
                  </Button>
                  <Button onClick={handleClose} color="primary">
                    Close
                  </Button>
                </DialogActions>

              </form>
              )}
            />
          </DialogContent>
      </Dialog>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Which ui library are you using?

Comment: Just edited OP... using React and Material UI @jean182

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For future readers, I fixed this by removing the validation parameter from the Material UI, uppercase Form tag and enforced validation using the standard, lowercase form tag.